# Nginx alias not working

Tags: nginx, alias

I'm trying to pass all traffic at location `^/[a-z0-9]{24}$`to index.html at a different root directory. I have my config set up like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;
    root /Users/me/sites/store_front/static;
    index index.html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;

    location ~ "^/[a-z0-9]{24}$" {
        alias /Users/me/web_app/static;
        try_files $uri index.html;
    }
}
```

For some reason when I curl this url I get a 404:

```
$ curl -I https://example.com/55c898e7faa137f42409d403

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 168
Connection: keep-alive
```

Does anyone know how to get this alias working?

#### update:

One caveat to this is that I need all the relative urls in index.html to load correctly:

```
<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
<script src="/javascript/main.js"></script>
```

These files actually exist in the `web_app` directory but nginx tries to load them from `store_front`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointing `^/[a-z0-9]{24}$` to `index.html` is easy. The resource files `/styles/main.css` and `/javascript/main.js` need to have unique URIs otherwise `nginx` does not know which files to serve.

If the `/styles` and `/javascript` prefix is also used by the store_front, you will need to isolate the individual files:

```
location = /styles/main.css {
    root /Users/me/web_app/static;
}
location = /javascript/main.js {
    root /Users/me/web_app/static;
}
location ~ "^/[a-z0-9]{24}" {
    root /Users/me/web_app/static;
    rewrite ^ /index.html break;
}
```

If the `/styles`, `/javascript` and `^/[a-z0-9]{24}$` URIs are all unique, you might combine the above into a single location:

```
location ~ "^/([a-z0-9]{24}|styles|javascript)" {
    root /Users/me/web_app/static;
    rewrite "^/[a-z0-9]{24}$" /index.html break;
}
```

Or even:

```
location ~ "^/([a-z0-9]{24}|styles/main.css|javascript/main.js)" {
    root /Users/me/web_app/static;
    rewrite "^/[a-z0-9]{24}$" /index.html break;
}
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to use multiple `root`s? I thought `alias` was best practice in a nested locations.

Comment: That seems to work, index.html load, but none of my scripts or styles for index.html load since they relative to the index page.

Comment: Answer updated: the terminating `$` on the location regex has been removed to match the URI of any relative resource files. And another `rewrite` has been added to handle these resource files.

Comment: This is so close, thanks for your help with this. Unfortunately, my static files aren't loading still. Wouldn't something like this: `rewrite "^/(styles|javascript)(/.*)" $2 break;` be more appropriate since `index.html` is being is located at `https://example.com/55c898e7faa137f42409d403`

Comment: Ok, major rewrite

Comment: Ah, unfortunately `styles/main.css` and `javascript/main.js` exist in both `web_app` and `store_front` directories. I wonder `proxy_pass` would be a better solution? I could create a separate config for both directories and them reverse proxy the to `web_app/index.html` from `store_front`.

Comment: URLs need to be unique.